# Where to download the Elsevier journal latex template?

Tags: templates, ubuntu, elsarticle

Please, I feel lost I am trying to dowsnload the LaTeX template of this journal `Robotics and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing` template (`Elsevier`)?
I do not find any information about the template in their web site:

[Elsevier.com](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/robotics-and-computer-integrated-manufacturing/call-for-papers/special-issue-on-industrial-internet-for-manufacturing)

I am using ubuntu, I have tried to use this template: 
els-cas-tem­plate

[els-cas-tem­plate](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.274.1553247377.4318.ctan-ann@ctan.org?lang=en)

But I do  not have the right format of robotics-and-computer-integrated-manufacturing which as I understand and I am not sure must look like the style of this paper [Safety and efficiency management in LGV operated warehouses](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rcim.2018.11.003)

Comment: Just follow these [instructions](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) and don't worry. Generally once they accept your paper, they'll take care of TeX styles or they'll ask you to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with your [first given link](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/robotics-and-computer-integrated-manufacturing/call-for-papers/special-issue-on-industrial-internet-for-manufacturing) in your question. Then you will find `search` (red circle marked with 1):

[image]

Then search for `latex template` (see red circle marked with 2) and click on the sign in red cirle marked with 3.

After that you get a new content and the first result seems to be what you are searching for (red circle marked with 4) ...

Seems you can use the class on ctan, but please read the instructions ...

[image: second page]

Answer (score 0):

I have not published in this journal, I have published in scholarly journals (Fisheries). You can get where you want with the following links.

[**1. Guide to Authors**](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/robotics-and-computer-integrated-manufacturing/0736-5845/guide-for-authors)

This will provide you with nitty-gritty details that you need to pay attention to (i.e., citation style, word count, section formatting etc.) for your specific journal.

[**2. elsarticle CTAN package**](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle)

This will provide you with article class you need for the correct formatting of your document. Generally, within a publisher most journals have similar if not the same formatting; if there are any minor differences you can refer to the [Guide to Authors](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/robotics-and-computer-integrated-manufacturing/0736-5845/guide-for-authors).

[**3. How to use elsarticle package**](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf)

This documentation gives an in-depth explanation of how to use the elsarticle package and how to use the different functions to format your document.